# Twilio : How to get video call metadata or call usage?

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I was using `twilio` client android `sdk` for video call in my android app.I had integrate the `twilio` android client api for the video call and video call goes smoothly.I just want to know how can i get the call statistics or call usage detail after completion of any video call ?

I had gone through the `Twilio` Docs but didn't find anything...kindly suggest me the solution if anyone has done..

Answer (score 0):

As of yet, [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) does not have a REST API.

You can get the data which you seek from logs in the console:

https://www.twilio.com/console/logs